# Proper way to parse with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I'm using SwityJSON to iterate through my JSON data and parse it. It's working fine, but I would like to make sure I'm using the syntax correctly and efficiently. Please review my code below:

```
                if let itemDict = json[0]["artists"].dictionaryValue {
                    for item in itemDict {
                        if let artist: Dictionary? = item.1.dictionaryValue {
                            // artist id
                            if let artistId = artist?["id"] {
                                if artistId.stringValue != nil {
                                    // add value to object
                                }
                            }
                            // title
                            if let title = artist?["title"] {
                                if title.stringValue != nil {
                                    // add value to object
                                }
                            }
                            // subtitle
                            if let subtitle = artist?["subtitle"] {
                                if subtitle.stringValue != nil {
                                    // add value to object
                                }
                            }
                            // image url
                            if let imageURL = artist?["imageURL"] {
                                if imageURL.stringValue != nil {
                                    // add value to object
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is new for all but [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial) has provided good tutorial. Try to learn from it. It helped me a lot.